# What is the maximum CSS integer of the different browsers?

Tags: css, browser, integer

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/integer):

> There is no official range of valid  values. Opera supports values up to 2<sup>15</sup>-1, IE up to 2<sup>20</sup>-1 and other browsers even higher.

I could not find any information on these "other browsers" though, and I'm also assuming there are differences between versions of the same browser as well.

So, what are the max supported value of a CSS integer in the different browsers out there?

Answer (score 0):

I created a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/goxepucegu/1/edit?html,css,output) to check whether the maximum was that of a 32-bit integer (`2147483647`) and it appears to be the case for Firefox 49, Chromium 53, and Opera 40, which were the only browsers I checked. Presumably, it's the same for at least a few versions back of the respective browsers, but I didn't bother to check.

Comment: You should also consider posting the code here as well as your interpretation of the results.